# Change mobile swipe view from a bar to indicator dots

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking to change the default scroll bar which comes with the css webkit to indicator dots. Below I have images of the current scrollbar, and then the desired scroll bar I'd like to implement.

[Current Scroll Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGMWF.png)

[Desired Scroll Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeKKZ.png)

Code:

```
.pw-swipe-view2 {
max-width:355px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  scroll-snap-coordinate: 0 0;
  scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
display:none;
}

<div class="pw-swipe-view2">
<section style="width: 352.44px; height: 300px; flex: 0 0 380px; scroll-snap-align: start;">
<div class="pw-column">
<div style="margin-right: 30px; width: 42%; height: auto; float: left; box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #F0F0F0; outline: 1px solid #CCCCCC;"><img style="width: 100%;" src="{{media url="Retirement.jpg"}}" alt="">
<p style = "padding:10px;font-size:1.6rem;">Retirement party for<span style = "color:#C7141A;font-weight:600;"> Chuck</span> and <span style = "color:#C7141A;font-weight:600;">Carl</span>.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="pw-column" style="padding-top: 0px;">
<div style="width: 42%; height: auto; float: left; box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #F0F0F0; outline: 1px solid #CCCCCC;"><img style="width: 100%;" src="{{media url="RheemConference.jpg"}}" alt="">
<p style = "padding:10px;font-size:1.6rem;"><span style = "color:#C7141A;font-weight:600;">Laura</span> and <span style = "color:#C7141A;font-weight:600;">Patrick</span> at a Rheem Conference.</p>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<section style="width: 352.44px; height: 288px; flex: 0 0 380px; scroll-snap-align: start;">
<div class="pw-column">
<div style="margin-right: 30px; width: 42%; height: auto; float: left; box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #F0F0F0; outline: 1px solid #CCCCCC;"><img style="width: 100%;" src="{{media url="fill3.jpg"}}" alt="">
<p style = "padding:10px;font-size:1.6rem;"><span style = "color:#C7141A;font-weight:600;">Noah, Marc,</span> and <span style = "color:#C7141A;font-weight:600;">Patrick</span> at the company picnic.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="pw-column" style="padding-top: 0px;">
<div style="width: 42%; height: auto; float: left; box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #F0F0F0; outline: 1px solid #CCCCCC;"><img style="width: 100%;" src="{{media url="fill4.jpg"}}" alt="">
<p style = "padding:10px;font-size:1.6rem;"><span style = "color:#C7141A;font-weight:600;">Shawn</span> and <span style = "color:#C7141A;font-weight:600;">Bryce</span> having fun at the Housecars.</p>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Is this a scroll bar what you want? It looks like a paginator.

Comment: I suppose a paginator would be more similar to what I'm trying to accomplish. As long as the user can swipe to access each of those pages.

Comment: Anyway the user will swipe on the cards themselves or in the dots?

Comment: The user would just swipe on the cards, then the dots would change from unfilled to filled when on the new set of cards (Then the previously filled dot before swiping would become unfilled).

Comment: The it is a paginator not a scroll.